# pass function value to output in innerhtml div

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys Im trying to pass the return value from the validation function to an innerhtml in the html section of the document. For some reason is not working.... Any help appreciated.

```
function validate(form) {
    fail  = validateName(form.name.value)
    fail += validateEmail(form.email.value)
    fail += validateCity(form.city.value)
    if (fail == "") return true
    else { alert(return document.getElementById('#errors').innerHTML=fail;}); return false}
    }

    function validateName(field) {
        if (field == "") return "No name was entered.\n"
        else if (field.length < 3) return "Name must be at least 3 characters.\n"
        else if (!/[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(field)) return "Name can only have alphabetical characters.\n"
        return ""
        }
    function validateEmail(field) {
        if (field == "") return "No email was entered.\n"
        else if (!((field.indexOf(".") > 0) && (field.indexOf("@") > 0)) || /[^a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]/.test(field)) return "The email address is invalid.\n"
        return ""
        }
    function validateCity(field) {
        if (field == "") return "No city was entered.\n"
        else if (field.length < 3) return "City must be at least 3 characters.\n"
        else if (!/[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(field)) return "City can only have alphabetical characters.\n"
        return ""
        }



  <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="subscribe" onSubmit="return validate(this)" id="subscribe" method="POST">
<div id="errors"></div>
<input name="name" autocomplete="off" required pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*$" title="Please enter only alphabetic characters" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name"/>


<input name="email" autocomplete="off" required id="email" type="email" title="Please enter your email address" placeholder="Your email address"/>

<input name="city" autocomplete="off" required pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*$" title="Please enter only alphabetic characters" id="city" placeholder="Your city"/>

<section id="buttons">
            <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset">

            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn" class="submitbtn" tabindex="7" value="Submit this!">

            <br style="clear:both;">
        </section>
```

Comment: Do you hate semicolon?

Comment: @JonathandeM. Why you say so?

Comment: `Ctr+A` then `Ctr+c` your HTML code then `Ctr+v` them here so that we can also see your HTML Codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **errors** in place of **#errors** and remove `return` from `alert` like

```
if (fail == "") return true;
else { 
   //use innerText in place of innerHTML if #errors is not a div
   document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML=fail; use errors in place of #errors
   alert(fail);
   return false
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly fine. How can I put a line break after the fail statement. Thank you so much @Rohan Kumar

Comment: Use `<br/>` in place of `\n` or make an `array` of `fail` messages and `join` using `<br/>` like `fail.join('<br/>');`

Answer (score 0):

For ethical coding,  you might need to avoid returning the value of a function inside the argument of a function or method:

Notice the line:

```
else { alert(return document.getElementById('#errors').innerHTML=fail;});
```

The **`return`** is passed as part of arguments of the **`alert()`**.... that seems NOT okay!

This causes `Syntax Errors`.